# Alterar mensagem de campo obrigatório

Tags: javascript, html5, checkbox

Como alterar a mensagem abaixo e permanecer com a simplicidade e coerência que preciso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$(function() {
  var requiredCheckboxes = $('.periodicidade :checkbox[required]');
  requiredCheckboxes.change(function() {
   if (requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
    requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
   }
   else {
    requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="periodicidade">
<input type="checkbox" required value=1>Segunda-feira
<input type="checkbox" required value=2>Terça-feira
<input type="checkbox" required value=3>Quarta-feira
<input type="checkbox" required value=4>Quinta-feira
<input type="checkbox" required value=5>Sexta-feira
<input type="checkbox" required value=6>Sábado
<input type="checkbox" required value=7>Domingo
</div>
```

Observações:

1. Obrigatório a marcação de no mínimo 1 (um) `checkbox`
2. Utilizar `setCustomValidity` para a alteração da mensagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde senhores,

> [RESOLVIDO] Segue abaixo a solução disponibilizada em outro fórum:

```js
var requiredCheckboxes = $('.periodicidade :checkbox[required]');

requiredCheckboxes.get(0).setCustomValidity('Mark at least one checkbox');

requiredCheckboxes.change(function() {
  if (requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
  requiredCheckboxes.get(0).setCustomValidity('');
    requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
  } else {
  requiredCheckboxes.get(0).setCustomValidity('Mark at least one checkbox');
    requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
  }
});
```